# Store a value in MySQL made from gmdate() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$vid_length = gmdate("H:i:s", $ytarr['length_seconds']);

$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (owner_id, video_url, vid_length, thumbnail_url, title) VALUES (:owner_id, :video_url :vid_length, :thumbnail_url, :title) ");
$query->execute(array(
    ':owner_id' => $_POST['owner_id'],
    ':video_url' => $youtube_link,
    ':vid_length' => $vid_length,
    ':thumbnail_url' => (string) $ytarr['thumbnail_url'],
    ':title' => (string) $ytarr['title']
));
```

If I remove the code related to vid_length, the other values get stored fine.
With vid_length in however, the query doesn't work.

I tried making the vid_length column time, datetime and also varchar/text while casting (string) to $vid_length.

Any suggestions to make this work?

Ps: $vid_length becomes of format 00:02:39 (after converting the seconds)
$ytarr['length_seconds'] is a number (ie 264s seconds)

Comment: can u post value of $ytarr['length_seconds'] and $vid_length?

Comment: ie: 00:02:39, which looked like mysql 'time' to me

Comment: that is vid_length, length_seconds would be 159

Comment: @naveengoyal any idea what I could test?

Comment: No..but you can try (string)$vid_length. this only just a try.may be its work...

Comment: hate this... was missing a comma between :video_url :vid_length,

Comment: 1) You are not doing error checking; you don't have to *guess* SQL errors, you can be notified of them. 2) How does the whole concept of *Greenwich Mean Time* apply to recoding lengths?

Comment: That was a way for me to get what I wanted. Another poster suggested SEC_TO_TIME() which I like better. I also displayed the errors which made me see that comma mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) in the query to perform the conversion .

Also you missed a coma between `:video_url` and `:vid_length`

```
VALUES (:owner_id, :video_url :vid_length, :thumbnail_url, :title)
```

Probably something like this should help :

```
/*
$vid_length = gmdate("H:i:s", $ytarr['length_seconds']);
*/
$query = "
    INSERT INTO videos
            (owner_id,  video_url,              vid_length,       thumbnail_url,  title)
    VALUES (:owner_id, :video_url, SEC_TO_TIME(:length_seconds), :thumbnail_url, :title)";

$query = $conn->prepare( $query );
$query->execute(array(
        ':owner_id' => $_POST['owner_id'],
        ':video_url' => $youtube_link,
        ':length_seconds' => $ytarr['length_seconds'],
        ':thumbnail_url' => (string) $ytarr['thumbnail_url'],
        ':title' => (string) $ytarr['title']
));
```

Comment: Thanks--the comma was indeed the error. I got to know about it when I finally started displaying errors.

Answer (score -1):

I would Just Insert It Into Your Database Directly By Making  Variables For Each Value Being Sent To The Database `(vid_length VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)`

```
$vid_length = gmdate("H:i:s",$ytarr['length_seconds']);
$owner_id = $_POST['owner_id'];
$thumbnail_url = (string) $ytarr['thumbnail_url'];
$title = (string) $ytarr['title'];

$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (owner_id, video_url, vid_length, thumbnail_url, title)
VALUES (:owner_id, :video_url, :vid_length, :thumbnail_url, :title) ");

$query->execute(array(
    ':owner_id' => $owner_id,
    ':video_url' => $youtube_link,
    ':vid_length' => $vid_length,
    ':thumbnail_url' => $thumbnail_url,
    ':title' => $title

));
```

Comment: The OP is using a modern library and protecting himself from SQL injection. Suggesting switching to a deprecated library and writing insecure code is terrible advice.

Comment: true i was using an example of from what was given

Comment: UPDATE: Would That Work Or Would That Still Be Insecure?

Comment: Please have a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). There's no need to waste time writing homegrown solutions. Furthermore, yours *alters* the data being submitted. And, of course, vulnerabilities found in the legacy mysql extension are not going to get fixed.

Comment: Thanks--that's actually what I am using right now too (I'm just not passing vars to other vars).